# I have created API in mockable.io and trying to call it from my iOS app, Every time it shows me 404. Don't know why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

API works well in postman, don't know what is wrong when calling from iOS.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://demo2051366.mockable.io/Authentication"];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: Going to your URL in browser returns "Mock not found" as well.

Comment: This seems to be a server error not iOS error